# How to number equations with a list environment

Tags: equations, lists, itemize

Hi I wish to number equations  with a list environment

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Lol
\begin{equation}
y_t=h_t(\hat{x}_{t|t-1})
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}
```

I want  `y_t=h_t(\hat{x}_{t|t-1})` in the same line of Lol...
Can you help me to find out a way?

Comment: In the same line? Just write inline formula with `$ $`. You can not number an inline expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has good alignments, but the text part of item (Lol and Hackety hack.)  shouldn't be too large:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
First an equation.
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sin(x)
\end{equation}
Then a list.
\begin{itemize}
\item Lol \hfill \makebox[0pt][r]{%
            \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
              \begin{equation}
                 y_t=h_t(\hat{x}_{t|t-1})
              \end{equation}
          \end{minipage}}
\item Hackety hack. \hfill \makebox[0pt][r]{%
            \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
              \begin{equation}
                 a = b
              \end{equation}
          \end{minipage}}
\end{itemize}
And another equation.
\begin{equation}
 g(x) = \cos(x)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This probably works really bad in a lot of cases:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\listequationnumber}{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}
\newcommand{\listequation}[1]{\hfill$\displaystyle #1$\hfill\listequationnumber}

\begin{document}
First an equation.
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sin(x)
\end{equation}
Then a list.
\begin{itemize}
\item Lol \listequation{y_t=h_t(\hat{x}_{t|t-1})}
\item Hackety hack. \listequation{a = b}
\end{itemize}
And another equation.
\begin{equation}
 g(x) = \cos(x)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solved my question.. But is  there any way to improve the equation alignment? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`paralist`](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/paralist/paralist.pdf) package, especially the `inparaenum` environment should be what you are looking for.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{inparaenum}[(1)]
\item lol
\item $y_t=h_t(\hat{x}_{t|t-1})$
\item lol
\end{inparaenum}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Oh, nice. But the equation is not numbered using the `equation` counter, is it? The number comes from the list.

Comment: @Sigur that's right, if the equation numbering *must* come through the `equation` environment, your comment holds true, at least to my knowledge one can't number inline expressions.

Comment: Thanks but the equation is not numbered using the equation counter, so this don't answer my question...