# Double tagged equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, enumerate, best-practices

In the following example
[image]

the inequality (2.26) is obtained in the environment `equation`, but the equations (2.27) and (2.28) by dirty tricks, destroying the structure of the document. This is because additional tags (i) and (ii) are needed on the left-hand side of lines. (This is, in fact, some kind of an enumeration).

How to obtain such additional tags in equations or even more: produce a list with equations of its elements?

I am trying to find better solutions then [How to number equations with a list environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88742/how-to-number-equations-with-a-list-environment)

*Remark.* According to some wishes a (very ugly) code snippet. I hope that it would be enough instead of MWE and I know, that one should not use LaTeX in the presented way.

```
Indukcja matematyczna pozwala przenieść nierówność \eqref{(2.25)} na dowolną liczbę składników:
\begin{equation}
\label{(2.26)}
 J(X_1+\ldots +X_n)\leqslant \alpha_1^2J(X_1)+\ldots +\alpha_n^2J(X_n),%$ \hfill (2.26) 
\end{equation}

\vspace{2mm}
\noindent gdzie $X_1,\ldots ,X_n$ są niezależne oraz $\alpha_i\in[0,1],\; \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=1$. Nierówność (2.26) udowodnili Stam (1959) oraz Blachman (1965), nie korzystając z lematu 2.2. Nierówność (2.26) można zapisać w kilku 
równoważnych postaciach:

\vspace{2mm}
\noindent$\;\;${\it (i) $\;\;\;J(\sqrt{\alpha_1}X_1+\ldots +\sqrt{\alpha_n}X_n)\leqslant \alpha_1J(X_1)+\ldots +\alpha_nJ(X_n)$;\hfill {\rm (2.27)}

\vspace{2mm}
\noindent$\;\;$(ii) $\;\;\displaystyle \frac{1}{J(X_1+\ldots +X_n)}\geqslant \frac{1}{J(X_1)}+\ldots +\frac{1}{J(X_n)}$;\hfill
{\rm (2.28)}
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: One common reason for using an `enumerate` environment is that one wants to be able to cross-reference the various items somewhere else in the text. However, given that the itemized material consists of already-enumerated equations (inequalities, actually), is it necessary to provide a second form of enumeration? Would the flow of the presentation suffer (or be enhanced?) if you placed the two last inequalities in an `align` environment (with alignment on the inequality symbol)?

Comment: @Andrew It is not a problem of errors, hence packages are rather meaningless (`amsmath` is obviously used). The code used for the fragment in the picture is really dirty, against LaTeX rules, so it is not included intentionally.

Comment: @Mico For some reasons author wants these `(i)`'s, but `enumerate` is only a suggestions. Labels on both sides of lines are pretty satisfactonary.

Comment: Czesc @PrzemysławScherwentke I think the solution might be to use the `subequations` environment from the `amsmath` [package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) that lets you do what you want. It is easy to use.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I agree that it is not a question of errors but it would be nice to have a realistic MWE to work with (I just posted the generic MWE comment from my clipboard).

Comment: I gather that "Nierówność" means either "equation" or "inequality". :-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Sorry for the confusion and misunderstanding, don't be afraid ;)

Comment: @Mico Nierówność=inequality. Corrected. :-)

Comment: I can't understand what the labels on the left are for. If the two equations are to be considered as a set, then `subequations` should be used, which would label them as 2.27a and 2.27b, with the possibility to refer to “Equations 2.27” by setting a `\label` after `\begin{subequations}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

**EDIT**

I decided that I didn't really like my first solution (see below) because it requires all of this "extra clutter" in order for it to work. So, I have written a custom [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) environment `equationate` (=`equation`+`enumerate`) that does the same thing except that it hides the clutter inside the environment.

The output is given above, which is exactly the same as for my first solution, but the input now only requires some equations inside an enumerate-like environment. These equations are automatically typeset as mathematics in `\displaystyle`. Even though it doesn't look like it above (I shrunk the image), the equation numbers are flush with the righthand margin.

Here is the new MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[width=80mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand\theequation{(\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation})}

\let\realItem=\item
\newcommand\EquationItem[1][\relax]{%
  \ifmmode\EndEquationItem\fi% close off math-mode from last item
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\realItem\else\realItem[#1]\fi%
  \refstepcounter{equation}$\displaystyle%
}
\newcommand\EndEquationItem{$\hfill\theequation}
\newlist{equationate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[equationate]{label=\roman*), before=\global\let\item\EquationItem,
                      after=\EndEquationItem\global\let\item\realItem}

\begin{document}
\section{Some equations}

  \begin{equationate}
    \item \sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac12 n(n+1)
    \item \sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac16n(n+1)(2n+1)
  \end{equationate}

\end{document}
```

Notice that because `equationate` is an [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) environment you can customise it on the fly in the usual way. For example,

```
  \begin{equationate}[label=\alph*)]
    \item \sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac12 n(n+1)
    \item \sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac16n(n+1)(2n+1)
  \end{equationate}
```

will print the item numbers as `a), b), ...`. Of course, if you change the values of `before` or `after` then everything will break. If you're keen it shouldn't be hard to add an option so that `\item*` suppresses the equation label for an item.

**Original solution**

I would use the following (using the `enumitem` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[width=80mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \section{Some equations}
  \renewcommand\theequation{(\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation})}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)]
      \item $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac12 n(n+1)$
      \refstepcounter{equation}\hfill\theequation
      \item $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac16n(n+1)(2n+1)$
      \refstepcounter{equation}\hfill\theequation
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This is not much of hack and it produces the image above.

Comment: @Mico I will try to reform:)

Comment: @Andrew +1. Nice trick, preserving the structure of a document.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, you're right it was an old image. I've updated it.

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't it be the easiest way to use an `align` or `alignat` here? I replaced the `\ldots` by `\dots` in between the binary operators as they are looking wrong.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{section}{2} 
    \setcounter{equation}{25}
    Indukcja matematyczna pozwala przenieść nierówność (2.25) na dowolną liczbę składników:
    \begin{equation}
        \label{(2.26)}
        J(X_1 + \dots + X_n) \leqslant \alpha_1^2J(X_1) + \dots + \alpha_n^2J(X_n),
    \end{equation}
    gdzie $X_1, \dots, X_n$ są niezależne oraz $\alpha_i\in[0,1],\; \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=1$. Nierówność (2.26) udowodnili Stam (1959) oraz Blachman (1965), nie korzystając z lematu 2.2. Nierówność (2.26) można zapisać w kilku 
    równoważnych postaciach:    
    \begin{alignat}{2}
        &(i)\qquad &&J(\sqrt{\alpha_1}X_1+ \dots +\sqrt{\alpha_n}X_n)\leqslant \alpha_1J(X_1)+ \dots +\alpha_nJ(X_n);\\
        &(ii)\qquad &&\displaystyle \frac{1}{J(X_1+ \dots +X_n)}\geqslant \frac{1}{J(X_1)}+ \dots + \frac{1}{J(X_n)};
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need the left labels flush left, you should go with a table I guess.

Comment: Between binary operators, one can use `\dotsb`, where the "b" stands for "binary".  See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122493/6376